# Impossible to change DNS records in .DE domain

Tags: dns, domain

I've being trying to change DNS records in a .DE domain (waverocker.de), but it's impossible! I have the same domain as .ORG and .CH and no problem there, but with .DE version it's impossible.

Always gives back an "error while updating domain name: Nameserver error". I'm checking with https://zonemaster.net and the only red error that I get it's that my IP refers to multiple nameservers.

How can I change my DNS records in this .DE domain? Why it works fine with other domains buy not with .DE?

Comment: I voted to close for lack of information - all domains have - but necessity - a similar DNS mechanism. At a wild guess you are having a problem related to a glue record - but that's the problem - you have not provided any details about the domain name (other then tld), nor the zone file.

Comment: @davidgo I've edited my post. Domain name is **waverocker.de** but as I said, I don't know what's wrong here. Or it's because I fill DNS records with 2 nameservers in the same IP or it's because I don't fill DNS records with IPv6 nameservers (don't know if this is a must for .DE domains)

Comment: Im not at my computer do I can't check easily right now, but if you only have 1 IP for the nameservers - that is most likely the problem.

Comment: So *what exactly* are you trying to change? The DNS contents? Or which nameservers the domain points to? How are you trying to change it? What domain provider did you register the domain with?

Answer (score 2):

If you were not aware, DE domains have specific DNS requirements. Specifically:

•You must have two authoritative nameservers

•You can verify if your nameservers are authoritative by visiting https://www.denic.de/en/service/tools/nast/ and entering the domain name and its nameservers to receive a reply.

•If the answer at ZoneCheck lists a non-authoritative answer at the top of the nameserver list, your nameservers are not authoritative.

•The nameservers in the domain name’s zone file must match the nameservers you are trying to use, or your nameservers are considered non-authoritative.

•Each nameserver must be on a separate class-C network.

•The first three octets cannot be the same. For example, 216.1.69.1 and 68.42.99.120 are valid. 216.1.69.1 and 216.1.69.2 are not valid.

•You must have a Start of Authority (SOA) refresh value between 10000 and 86400 seconds.

•You must have a retry value between 1800 and 28800 seconds.

•You must have a Time to Live (TTL) value between 180 and 345600.

•You must specify a Mail Exchanger (MX) record that resolves to a valid mail server for the life of the domain name registration, not just for the registration itself

•Serial numbers for all nameserver zones for the domain name must match.